# Running MySQL on port 3307 Windows

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I have 2 instances of XAMPP. Each instance of xampp represents a different PHP version. I want to be able to open up either xampp control panel and start apache/mysql successfully. The mysql data should be kept separate. Therefore, I want the second xampp to run on port 3307 while the first instance of xampp remains on 3306.

**The problem**
Regardless of setting the port to 3307 in my.ini, clicking "start" in the xampp control panel spawns a 3306 version of mysqld.

**More interesting**
If I go to base directory -> manually run mysql_start.bat, it will spawn the 3307 version correctly. Even though this is a solution to my problem, its not ideal. I want it controlled thru the xampp control panel. And I want to figure out why the heck this is happening!

**Other Notes**
I have also set the port 3307 in

- php\php.ini
- phpMyAdmin\config.inc
- xampp-control.ini

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the Service port configuration on xampp-control.ini -

```
[ServicePorts]
Apache=80
ApacheSSL=443
MySQL=3306
FileZilla=21
FileZillaAdmin=14147
Mercury1=25
Mercury2=79
Mercury3=105
Mercury4=106
Mercury5=110
Mercury6=143
Mercury7=2224
TomcatHTTP=8080
TomcatAJP=8009
Tomcat=8005
```

Hope this will help .